# Can I host ownCloud & a Wordpress blog at the same URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, web-hosting, owncloud

I have a Wordpress blog hosted by Bluehost. I am now looking in to setting up ownCloud and I was wondering if and how I could set up both services on at same website. (I realize I'll probably have to do something so that the ownCloud is installed at mysite.com/cloud or something.)

I'm not totally sure that this is the right Stack Site for this question, but I think it is.

Comment: I just did the same thing. on http://www.ljtd.eu is the usual site and https://www.ljtd.eu is running owncloud, works pretty good. If you need the the server config for this let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a subdirectory as you wish and use mysite.com/subdirectory to start installation of ownCloud.